# Complex query, getting the sum of a group of brands django

Tags: django, django-models

So here is the following issue, i am basically trying to bring up a query that display a top 10 brands table. And i am currently stuck at trying to 'join up' the brands.
As you can clearly see, i am uncapable of putting the brands at the same group and count the number of sales, of that specific brand group. I tried the following query, but it didnt work out

```
query2= DataDB.objects.annotate(marcas=Count('marca')).order_by('marcas')[:10]
```

And here is my tables code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <th>Marca</th>
        <th>N* de vendas</th>
    </thead>
    {%for q in query2 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{q.marca}}</td>
        <td>{{q.marcas}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor%}
</table>
```

Would really appreciate a little help here, dont actually know if the issue is on display or query.

[image]

Everything there is only one  model object.

```
class DataDB(models.Model):
marca=models.CharField(max_length = 30,error_messages={'required':'Favor inserir uma marca'})

modelo=models.CharField(max_length = 60,error_messages={'required':'Favor inserir um modelo'})

motor=models.CharField(max_length = 60,error_messages={'required':'Favor inserir um motor'})
```

Comment: Please show your models...

Comment: Done, but here is the deal there is only one brand model, which is the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform a group by which doesn't happen automatically just by using an aggregation function (unless this aggregation is with a related model), you need to use the [`values` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values) method of a queryset to perform a group by:

```
query2= DataDB.objects.values('marca').annotate(marcas=Count('marca')).order_by('marcas')[:10]
```

> **Note**: Your `marca` being a `CharField` is not a normalized database schema ideally it should be a **foreign key** to another
> model.

Comment: Oh thanks , i will take that in consideration. Just a note since is a top 10 you forgot the - after order_by( since it is a top 10 i had to add it, nonetheless the main issue is fixed.

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 top 10 from the bottom ;) I did notice that but since you didn't put it there I didn't either.